# Select a single row when item categorised in two specific categories [MySql]

Tags: mysql

can I return a single instance of a row after using a join on a categories table.

**Entries**

```
| id | Name   | 
| 1  | Johnny |
| 2  | Steve  |
| 3  | Bam    |
```

**Categories**

```
| cat_id | Name        | 
| 1      | Season one  |
| 2      | Season two  |
| 3      | Season three|
```

**Category Posts**

```
| id | cat_id | 
| 1  | 1      |
| 1  | 2      |
| 1  | 3      |
| 2  | 2      |
| 2  | 3      |
| 3  | 1      |
```

What I want to do is select all cast where members that have been in **season 2 and 3**, they must have been in both and I only want a single instance returned.

**Expected output**

```
| id | Name   | 
| 1  | Johnny |
| 2  | Steve  |
```

How would I got about selecting these? I've thought about grouping the user based on their name however because I'm selecting **IN ("2", "3")** I get some users that have been in two but not three and the expected results are wrong.

Thanks

Comment: categories look an awful lot like seasons !?!

Comment: Anyway... `GROUP BY... HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] ...) = n` where DISTINCT is optional, and n is equal to the number of arguments in `IN()`

Comment: I'm not following? @Strawberry - the content to some degree is irrelevant I was going to use cars and car history, it's the concept I'm after, selecting a single item after multiple joins.

Comment: It's the concept that I've provided!

Comment: The linked duplicate question has multiple different approaches to this question, including the approach @Strawberry has kindly outlined.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub query

```
    SELECT id,name from Entries where id in (select a.id from (select id from 
category_post WHERE cat_id=2) as a,(select id from category_post WHERE cat_id=3) as b where a.id=b.id)
```